# Is shell scripting in perl in range of this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is shell scripting in perl in range of this site?

or is perl hacking for SO?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but see [Are questions about CPAN ok?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/are-questions-about-cpan-ok), and the similar question for shell scripting, which has already been asked at [least](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84/shell-scripting-on-topic) [twice](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/142/is-it-ok-to-ask-bash-language-questions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you shell script in Perl? Perl is not a shell.

In any sense I think it depends on the nature of your Perl. Perl is required by one of the Unix or Linux standards. It is Unix, in a sense, where, for example, Ruby is not, because of this requirement.

I'm going to use [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3675/how-can-i-get-a-base64-encoded-shax-on-the-cli/3691#3691) to illustrate what kind of Perl I think is acceptable here. Essentially these are 1 liners. I'd definitely avoid anything over 10 lines.

However, I think it'd be best if you didn't ask Perl Questions here, SO is much more suited for these questions that here. I don't think we'd allow shell scripting if it wasn't so integral to Unix. On the flip side, if you ask a generic question that you know is likely to result in a Perl answer, [like I did](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3675/29) (and yes I already knew about the Perl solution), I'm ok with that. If you ask How do I take X Perl and convert it to Shell, or vice versa, I'm ok with that. I may also be ok with "what does X Perl do" if it seems fairly admin-ish. If it seems too programming-ish it probably doesn't belong here.

Am I making any sense?

Comment: I think so, but my first idea was the purpose of the script and not the size.

Comment: This makes sense; answers to "how do I do this on the CLI" that involve perl make sense, but "how do I write this in Perl?" probably don't, unless they're really trivial

Comment: Something like that :)

Comment: @Johan I'm thinking complexity... something simple should be accomplish-able in only a few lines... where something complex will take more, and is probably beyond our scope.

Comment: It is easier to mark a line in the sand based on purpose of question then on the complexity, but I see what you mean.